# ASP.Net - How do I programatically edit external config files at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net

By external config files, I mean .config files other than web.config. I've seen all the examples on how to edit web.config at runtime, but I want to edit a config file referenced by a configSource for appSettings. I want to modify only the external file and I will handle the app recycle.

Ideally I would like to use a built-in class to deal with the edits, but if the only option is a manual File open/parse, etc, then sobeit.

The general idea behind all this being a Settings page that is viewed at app startup, user sets their particulars and then saves the changes, then the real app starts up. quick and easy install app/configure page, so I'd like to leverage .config if at all possible.

Thanks!

FOLLOWUP - Quick Snippet to use XmlDocument to change an appSetting key value:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/my.config");

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);

XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/appSettings/add[@key='myKey']");
node.Attributes[1].Value = "myVal";

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(path, null);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
doc.WriteTo(writer);
writer.Flush();
writer.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should, at the very least, be able to utilize the classes in the [System.Xml Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to read the settings files as any old XML file.

Answer (score 7):

The usual code for editing standard configuration files goes like this:

```
string cfgPath = Path.Combine(targetDir, "myApp.config");
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = cfgPath };

var cf = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap,
    ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
cf.AppSettings.Settings["somekey"].Value = "newvalue";

cf.Save();
```

*Code version is .NET 3.5, by the way.*

You probably need to set the correct permissions as well. Note that if you don't have the standard configuration file layout (root node is `<configuration>`) this code will throw an exception.

Comment: This is a great example, but throws an error because the external config file does not have a <configuration> root node, root node has to be <appSettings> when using a configSource file.

Comment: @Stuart: yes, you're right, you need to have a <configuration> root node. I was assuming that you were using a standard config file.

Comment: The reliance on needing to use <appSettings> is due to the fact that this file is referenced as a configSource property in the web.config. Thank you for your timely help though.